# C++ - Is there a way to get an identifier as a string?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to get the identifier of an function or object of a class as a string?
Like:

```
void SomeFunc() {}

int main()
{
    SomeClass classObject(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << getName(classObject) << std::endl;
    // Will print "classObject"
    SomeClass name;
    std::cout << getName(name) << std::endl;
    // Will print "name"
    std::cout << getName(SomeFunc) << std::endl;
    // Will print "SomeFunc"
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you need that?

Comment: Why aren't you just printing the string literal?

Answer (score 5):

you have the stringification operator for macros:

```
#define getName(a) #a
```

will turn anything it gets as an argument to a quoted string

```
getName(something) turns into "something"
```